# Determine if the following function is continuous in $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Assignment:

> Determine if the following function is continuous in $(0,0)$.
>   $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
> 1& ,x≤ 0, y \in \mathbb{R}
> \\
> x^{y^2}& , x > 0, y\in \mathbb{R}
> \end{cases}$$

I think $f$ is not continuous. Using that $x^{y^2} = \exp(\ln(x) \cdot y^2)$ I thought I could find a path to show that, but I don't see it.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you have your piece wise conditions backwards.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I corrected a few errors, sorry.

Comment: Is $y$ really just a number in $\mathbb{R}$? I'm not sure why you don't just say that $y$ is fixed then.

Comment: Yes, $y$ is really arbitary. Can I just fix $y$ and take the limit of $x$ to $0$? That'd be pretty lame.

Comment: That would indeed be lame, but that's what I'm thinking...

Comment: @KitKat Yup, it really is that simple. :)

Comment: Is this for Real Analysis or Multivariable Calc.? If Real Analysis, have you proved L-Hospital's rule yet?

Comment: I'm still unsure about this solution. I don't think I can just fix $y$, since I have to let $y$ or at least $y_n \rightarrow 0$, and then consider the function values. Fixing $y \neq 0$ doesn't prove anything, does it. - @Clarinetist Yes, we have.

Comment: I am likewise unsure. I'm going to grab my Real Analysis text and see if I can figure out a way to do this one...

Comment: Try something like $x = e^{-1/y^2}$

Comment: haha I was super late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the path $x=e^{-1/y^{2}}$ as $y\rightarrow 0$.